# Sinch Android SDK with Parse SDK

Tags: android, parse-platform, webrtc, sinch

i am currently using Parse SDK for user registration and authentication. It is working correctly but it shows every user in the parse datastore. How can i create separate userlist for each user?
Can i implement WhatsApp like registration feature on Sinch SDK for Android?

Comment: You probably can, does that answer your question?

Comment: Actually my question contain two questions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain what you mean by a WhatsApp registration?

Edit: According to this Quora question (http://www.quora.com/WhatsApp-Messenger/Does-WhatsApp-have-an-API), Whatsapp does not have a public API.

Comment: WhatsApp registration mean that how can a user authenticate his phone to the WhatsApp server